# IKEv2 VPN connected but no Internet

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, opensuse, strongswan

There are a lot of questions on SE regarding this and I tried nearly all of them. Unfortunately none solved my problem.

I followed the instruction on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ikev2-vpn-server-with-strongswan-on-ubuntu-16-04), but adapted it a little to fit my OS (openSuSE Leap 42.3). To be clear, `/etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2` is modified as follows:

```
FW_SERVICES_EXT_UDP="500 4500"
FW_ROUTE="yes"
FW_MASQUERADE="yes"
FW_MASQ_NETS=""
FW_SERVICES_EXT_IP="esp ah"
```

My `/etc/ipsec.conf`:

```
config setup
  charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
  uniqueids=no

conn ikev2-vpn
  auto=add
  compress=no
  type=tunnel
  keyexchange=ikev2
  fragmentation=yes
  forceencaps=yes
  ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024
  esp=aes256-sha1
  dpdaction=clear
  dpddelay=300s
  rekey=no
  left=%any
  leftid=@server.com
  leftcert=/etc/ipsec.d/certs/vpn-server-cert.pem
  leftsendcert=always
  leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
  right=%any
  rightid=%any
  rightauth=eap-mschapv2
  rightdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
  rightsourceip=10.10.10.0/24
  rightsendcert=never
  eap_identity=%identity
```

Also modified `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc = 1
```

My Azure Inbound Rules:

```
Allow UDP 500, 4500
```

Default outbound rules.